# Comma before "with"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, prepositions

I'm watching *Batman* with Sara.

or

I'm watching *Batman*, with Sara.

Sara = my friend, not an actress. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'm watching *Batman* with Sara.  - This would indicate you are physically watching *Batman* together with Sara.  If Sara is your friend, I would leave the comma out.

or

I'm watching *Batman*, with Sara. - This would imply that Sara is an actress in *Batman*.
Example:  I'm watching *Grease*, with John Travolta.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence without the comma, the sentence construction closely associates Sara with either you or *Batman*. For example, you and Sara are watching *Batman* together. Less idiomatically, you could be saying that you are acting as a [chaperone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaperone_%28social%29) for *Batman* and Sarah.

The comma interrupts the second sentence, so the second version asserts that you, as an individual, are watching Batman. It holds Sara's involvement as a separate idea. Depending on context, it can emphasise her relationship with you or *Batman*, or to assert her lack of relationship with you or *Batman*.

Note that writing *Batman* in italics doesn't necessarily make it the title of a movie.